# How to make javascript functions work with .when .then toexecute in proper order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've read many posts on this topic and think I should be using $.when and .then or .done for what I need, but not sure how to make it happen.  Any help you can provide is appreciated.

I have two functions that can run simultaneously, and a third function that can only run after the first two are complete.  Here's a basic breakdown of what I'm doing.

```
function one() {
  //do lots of stuff to get variable values set
  return $.post("sess_push.php", {hotel:hotel, hlng:hLng, hlat:hLat})
            .done(function( data ) {
            console.log("Done in function one");
            alert( "Done in function one" );
        });
} //end function one

function two() {
  //do lots of stuff to get variable values set
  return $.post("sess_push.php", {metro:metro, lat:lat, lng:lng})
        .done(function( data ) {
        console.log("Done with function 2");
        alert ("Done with function 2");
    });
} //end function two

function three() {
    console.log("Starting function 3");
        alert("Starting function 3");
        $.post("itenerary.php", {})
        .done(function( data ) {
          $("#itenerary").html(data);
        });
} // end function three
```

How do I use promises and/or deferred to get these to execute in the order I need?

I've tried to use the following $.when, but function three runs before the other two are done.
$.when(one(), two()).then( three, myFailure );

Comment: it should work as you expect - get rid of the alerts, does that help?

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/0enmpn0v/ - using `$.Deferred` instead of `$.post` - but promises are promises

Comment: I took out the alerts, but it still doesn't execute in the desired order.  When it runs it almost always says "done with function 2", "starting function 3", then "done in function one".  I'll simplify my scripts and try to get the base working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are better ways to make this work, but this is what did the trick for me.  Thanks to Jaromanda X for providing the base for what I used to get it working.  if others have ways to optimize this, I'm all for it.

```
function one() {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  //do lots of stuff to get variable values set

  $.post("sess_push.php", {hotel:hotel, hlng:hLng, hlat:hLat});
  console.log("Done in one");
  d.resolve();
  return d.promise();
} //end function one

function two() {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  //do lots of stuff to get variable values set

  $.post("sess_push.php", {metro:metro, lat:lat, lng:lng});
  console.log("Done with two");
  d.resolve();
  return d.promise();
} //end function two

function three() {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    $.post("itenerary.php", {})
    .done(function( data ) {
        $("#itenerary").html(data);
    console.log("Done in 3");
    });
    d.resolve();
    return d.promise();

} // end function three
```